# can't access HTTP POST authorization token in Python

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, http-headers, jwt, restful-authentication

I'm building a django JWT API and have the login/logout/register routes done. I'm trying to make a new route that accepts json data in a post request from an authenticated user and eventually adds it to the user's database.

I'm testing this route with Postman by sending the Authroization key in the header, as well as json data. In my views.py file I can successfully identify the post request and print the json data, but can't find the authorization header anywhere. If I try to print out 'request.headers' it says "AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'headers'"

views.py:

def HomePageView(request):

```
if request.method=='POST':
    print('its a post')
    print('request: ' + str(request))
    print('request.body: ' + str(request.body))
    print('request.method: ' + str(request.method))
    print('request.headers: ' + str(request.headers))

    return StreamingHttpResponse('response')
```

Postman:
[image]

[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Saying `print('request: ' + str(request))` doesn't show too much. Try `print('request: ' + str(request.__dict__))` or something like that. It will show you all the attributes of the request. Then you will notice whether `headers` are there or not. Another thing to look for: Why are you seeing the class `WSGIRequest` instead of the class `HttpRequest`?

Comment: thank you, using the __dict__ allowed me to see the jwt is getting saved to the field "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"